# How can I continue an if and else statement?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I am trying to make an app that for each time you press the button a new US state comes up, so far I've gotten to Alaska and don't know how to continue. Here is the code I have produced thus far:

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

if([hellolabel.text isEqualToString:@"Alabama"])
{

hellolabel.text = @"Alaska";

}

else

{

hellolabel.text = @"Alabama";

}

}
```

Comment: Change tag from `C` to `objective-c` to reach the proper audience.

Comment: Question is not clear... each time you need different different states?

Comment: yes, new state each time I hit the button like cklick 1 "Alabama" click 2 "alaska" click 3 "Arizona" and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the state names in an array

```
  NSArray *states = @[@"Alabama",@"Alaska",...]

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender 
 {
   NSString *state = [states objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(states.count)];
   hellolabel.text = state;
 }
```

This will give you random state names

If you want it in an order

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   NSArray *_states;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
   _states = @[@"Albama",@"Alaska"];
 }
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender 
 {
    static NSInteger position = 0;
    if(position == _states.count-1)
    {
     position = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      position++;
    }
   NSString *state = [_states objectAtIndex:position];
   hellolabel.text = state;
 }
```

Comment: I did so, but there comes an error on the - (IBAction)button1:(id)sender saying it expected an expression?

Comment: Did u include header file #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: no, I'm pretty new at this so I'm not really sure how :P

Comment: where do I put in the states if I want to get them in order? as I said, Im new at this :P

Comment: Is this for iOS? then do it viewDidLoad.. i mean there you can create the states array

Comment: yes it's for iOS, it looked a little complicated, do you have any tips for me to just continue what i started?

Comment: Its not complicated.. You cannot continue with what u started it needs a lot of checking. I will update my answer

Comment: I've pasted it in, but on the line  hellolabel.text = state;
there is an error saying "use of undeclared idetifyer "state" what does this mean?

Comment: Ensure that ur code is same as    NSString *state = [_states objectAtIndex:position];
   hellolabel.text = state;

Comment: I fixed it, but it also shows an error on else{ saying expected expression

Comment: One bracket was missing i fixed.. check again code

Comment: the error was fixed, but when I add : UIViewController behind @interface ViewController it shows an error saying: duplicate interface definition for class viewcontroller?

Comment: Just copy {
   NSArray *_states;
}    to your @interface section. Dude.. you have go too far in objective c and iOS..  better go through some textbook and tutorials

Comment: I got it to work now, thank you very much for your help dude! I knoe, when I started this project I thought it would be much easier, but I see now, I've got a lot to learn!